# Custom Posttype URL

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I create custom post type code is below

```
function jobs_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Jobs', 'Post Type General Name', 'OceanWP' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Job', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'OceanWP' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Job Archives', 'OceanWP' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Job Attributes', 'OceanWP' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Job:', 'OceanWP' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'OceanWP' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'OceanWP' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'OceanWP' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Jobs list', 'OceanWP' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Jobs list navigation', 'OceanWP' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Jobs list', 'OceanWP' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'career/jobs',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Job Template', 'OceanWP' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'jobs', ' jobs_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 8,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-businessman',
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'career/jobs' ),
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'jobs', $args );
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'jobs_post_type', 0 );
```

But slug doesn't work.

What is the solution for slug? I want to be domain.com/**career/jobs**/job-post-name

Thank you

Comment: Have you flushed permalinks? Just visit _Settings > Permalinks_ and see if it works after that. Also, you've defined `rewrite` in the post type args twice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and everything seems to work fine except `'rewrite'               => $rewrite,`, so I just commented this out, flushed permalinks and it works as expected.

So I have this

```php
function jobs_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Jobs', 'Post Type General Name', 'OceanWP' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Job', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'OceanWP' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Job Archives', 'OceanWP' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Job Attributes', 'OceanWP' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Job:', 'OceanWP' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'OceanWP' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Jobs', 'OceanWP' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'OceanWP' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'OceanWP' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'OceanWP' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Jobs list', 'OceanWP' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Jobs list navigation', 'OceanWP' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Jobs list', 'OceanWP' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Job', 'OceanWP' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Job Template', 'OceanWP' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'jobs', ' jobs_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 8,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-businessman',
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'career/jobs' ),
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'jobs', $args );
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'jobs_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: Hi, I changed but I see that we have in Settings->Permalinks set up on /%category%/%postname%/ custom structure. This is a problem or not?

Comment: Try, I used post name alone